# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java310.dll:

Tags: java, spring, opencv, opencv3.0

I am Using windows 7 ultimate, Java 1.7 update version 75, opencv 3.1 and spring-tool-suite-3.7.3.RELEASE-e4.5.2-win32-x86_64 version.

I had extracted opev in c:\opencv after that I was set the user library in STS like below

[image]

I had wriiten following snippet for environment testing which gives me error

```
package com.opencv.test;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Hello{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
        System.out.println( "mat = " + mat.dump() );
    }
}
```

I got following error

```
C:\opencv\build\java\x64
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:C:\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java310.dll: 
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.opencv.test.Hello.main(Hello.java:10)
```

Please help to resolve this. I had already checked all links and stackoverflow where having same type of question and those answer didn't work for me. And after running this program I get following error too..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the x86 folder instead of x64 for the native path. Depending on your OS / JRE Version this could be the issue